# Calculate GPA for a student

Tags: java, arrays

Create a Java program that will read an array of letter grades that belongs to a student named John, as follows :

char John[] = {'A','B','A','C','F','B','A','D','A','C'};

The grade points for each grade is as follows:

A=4,B=3,C=2,D=1,F=0

Your program is to read each elements inside the array, validate the letter grade (which must be A, B, C, D or F), match the grade with appropriate grade points, and display the Grade Point Average(GPA) for John. Your program is to stop processing when your reach the last index of the array.

Here what i had tried but cannot get the right GPA.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{

    int gradepoint;
    char grade = ' ';
    double sum = 0;

    char John [] = {'A','B','A','C','F','B','A','D','A','C'};

    for (char c : John) {
    switch(c)
    {
    case 'A' : gradepoint = 4; break;
    case 'B' : gradepoint = 3; break;
    case 'C' : gradepoint = 2; break;
    case 'D' : gradepoint = 1; break;
    case 'F' : gradepoint = 0; break;
    }
    }

    for (int counter = 0; counter < John.length; counter++) {
        sum += John[counter];
    }
    double gpa = sum/10;

    System.out.println("GPA : " + gpa );
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

For each iteration through the array, add the value of the letter to the sum, and then divide the sum by the size of the array.

```
for (char c : John) {

            switch(c)
            {
                case 'A' : gradepoint = 4; break;
                case 'B' : gradepoint = 3; break;
                case 'C' : gradepoint = 2; break;
                case 'D' : gradepoint = 1; break;
                case 'F' : gradepoint = 0; break;
            }

            sum += gradepoint;
}

double gpa = sum/John.length;
System.out.println("GPA : " + gpa ); // GPA: 2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum += John[counter];` is adding letters to your `sum` (you need to perform your `switch` **in** the loop). You also forgot to check that the grade(s) were valid. You wanted something like

```
double sum = 0, count = 0;
char John[] = { 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'F', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'C' };
for (char c : John) {
    switch (c) {
    case 'A':
        sum += 4;
        count++;
        break;
    case 'B':
        sum += 3;
        count++;
        break;
    case 'C':
        sum += 2;
        count++;
        break;
    case 'D':
        sum += 1;
        count++;
        break;
    case 'F':
        count++;
        break;
    default:
        System.err.printf("%c is not a valid grade.%n", c);
    }
}
double gpa = sum / count;

System.out.println("GPA : " + gpa);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though answers are posted already, but I wanted to give you a piece of advice.

In such situations, I feel that using `Map` is a better option in comparison to `if` or `switch` in terms of performance as well as simplicity.

Here is my code using Map and Stream:

```
Character John [] = {'A','B','A','C','F','B','A','D','A','C'};
Map<Character, Integer> gradeValues = new HashMap<>();

gradeValues.put('A', 4);
gradeValues.put('B', 3);
gradeValues.put('C', 2);
gradeValues.put('D', 1);
gradeValues.put('F', 0);

OptionalDouble val = Arrays.asList(John).stream()
                        .map(c -> gradeValues.get(c)).mapToInt(g -> (int) g)
                        .average();

System.out.println("GPA: " + val.getAsDouble());
```